# SQL in clause with dummy rows

Tags: sql, in-clause, dummy-data

I'd really like know if it's possible to do a select statement, which returns exactly same records, that we put into **in** clause?

Sample:

```
select * from table
where table_id in (1, 2, 3, 666);
```

This table for an example has only id-s from 1 to 100, so this select will return only three rows. What I need to do, to get also one (probably null or dummy) row for 666?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use union:

```
select * from table
where table_id in (1, 2, 3);
union
select 666 as table_id, other_fields_with_dummy_values_in_table from dual;
```

is how you could do it in Oracle. The `from dual` might vary depending on what database system you're using.

Just be aware that if you use union, your dummy query MUST select the same records as the real query.

Comment: Your solution requires that you know when defining the statement which values are in the table and which are not.

Comment: @Frank: Well, you could use dynamic SQL to build the dummy list if you want to set it up programmatically, but the way that the OP talks about it, it sounds to me like they already know what will need to be a dummy ahead of time. But yeah, that could use some clarification I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can select without a table

Just do a UNION with your query

```
select table_id, some_column from table
where table_id in (1, 2, 3, 666);
union
select 666, 'dummy_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a table `numbers` containing all numbers from, say, 1 to 1000000 (in fact enough that your range of input values is covered), you could run the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM numbers left outer join table on table.table_id = numbers.number
 WHERE numbers.number in (1, 2, 3, 666)
```

If you use a DBMS that offers a better solution, like e. g. SQL Anywhere with it's [sa_rowgenerator](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbreference/sa-rowgenerator-sysproc.html) procedure, you can replace the table `numbers` with a procedure call, and do not have a limit of a maximum number.

Comment: That would work until he needs  a dummy value that's not in `numbers.number`.

Comment: Yes, that is a restriction - at least for many DBMSes, but e. g. SQL Anywhere offers a solution with a system procedure. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` clause is a boolean predicate, so you'll need to replace it with a dummy recordset:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  666 AS id
        ) q
LEFT JOIN
        mytable m
ON      m.id = q.id
```

In `SQL Server 2008`, you can run this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @mydata d
LEFT JOIN
        mytable t
ON      t.id = d.id
```

with `@mydate` is a table variable, passed as a parameter from the client.

In `PostgreSQL`, you can run this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  :arr[s] AS id
        FROM    generate_series(1, array_upper(:arr, 1)) s
        ) q
LEFT JOIN
        mytable t
ON      t.id = q.id
```

where `:arr` is an array `[1, 2, 3, 666]`, also passed from the client as the parameter.

In `Oracle`, you can do:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE(:mycol) q
LEFT JOIN
        mytable t
ON      t.id = q.id
```

, where `:mycol` is a variable of collection type, passed from the client.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of it is: you'd need to have that data "enter" the query as a data set. Data found in where clauses is never "added" to the query, they are only used to filter existing data out.

A quick example:

```
DECLARE @MustInclude (Value  int  not null)

INSERT @MustInclude (Value) values (1)
INSERT @MustInclude (Value) values (2)
INSERT @MustInclude (Value) values (3)
INSERT @MustInclude (Value) values (666)

SELECT *
 from @MustInclude mi
  left outer join MyTable mt
   on mt.Value = mi.Value
```